# big endian order in smartpy

Tags: smartpy, encoding

def tb(l):
return b''.join(map(lambda x: x.to_bytes(1, 'big'), l))

The above function takes a list of number and is being converted into bytes,

and the returned value is used this way,

base58.b58encode_check(tb([6, 161, 161]) + v).decode()

here v is also a byte data type.

How do we achieve this in smartpy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `string_of_nat` in [stringManipulation.py](https://smartpy.io/ide?template=stringManipulations.py).

```
def string_of_nat(params):
    c   = sp.map({x : str(x) for x in range(0, 10)})
    x   = sp.local('x', params)
    res = sp.local('res', [])
    sp.if x.value == 0:
        res.value.push('0')
    sp.while 0 < x.value:
        res.value.push(c[x.value % 10])
        x.value //= 10
    return sp.concat(res.value)
```

Similarly you can compute a map like `c` in this example that associates every x to the encoded version. Then when you have this map, you can use it in your contract.

1. Do this computation in Python (outside SmartPy).
2. Create a map that associates every `x` to the encoding you just computed.
3. Use this map.

Comment: I don't think I understood the answer, I need to achieve the above encoding in smartpy inside a contract.

Comment: I updated my answer, is it clear now?

Comment: so basically I think I understand what you are saying but I am having hard time converting a number to big endian bytes, x.to_bytes(1, 'big') the way it is done in python. I am trying to achieve this in smartpy